# My Winforms C# project designer gets annihilated by my C++/CLI project

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, c++-cli, windows-forms-designer

I've had lots of experience working with C++/CLI in the last several years, and if there's one thing I know, it's that mixed mode DLL's are bad for designing.

I have project a CSPROJECT, which depends on CPPPROJECT (using a project reference, copylocal=true, versionspecific=false, copylocalsattelitedpeendances=false).

Any time i try to open a form or usercontrol from CSPROJECT, I just get: `system.exception` was thrown.

I've tried fuslogvw, and it does not bind any failures to disk.  I've tried opening a second devenv to debug, but it just breaks at the same spot the designer shows in its callstack.  Here is the csproj snippet for my CPPPROJECT reference:

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\dfResultsStructures\dfResultsStructures.csproj">
  <Project>{D93C5625-0EB1-4645-95C8-F389758521EE}</Project>
  <Name>dfResultsStructures</Name>
  <Private>False</Private>
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
</ProjectReference>
```

And below is the callstack

```
   Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown.    

Instances of this error (1)  

1.   Hide Call Stack 

at VSLangProj.Reference.get_Path()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.VSTypeResolutionService.AddProjectDependencies(Project project)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.VSTypeResolutionService.AssemblyEntry.get_Assembly()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.VSTypeResolutionService.AssemblyEntry.Search(String fullName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreTypeCase, Boolean allowPrivate, Assembly& assembly, String description)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.VSTypeResolutionService.AssemblyEntry.Search(String fullName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreTypeCase, Assembly& assembly, String description)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.VSTypeResolutionService.SearchProjectEntries(AssemblyName assemblyName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreTypeCase, Assembly& assembly)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.VSTypeResolutionService.SearchEntries(AssemblyName assemblyName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, Assembly& assembly, ReferenceType refType)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.VSTypeResolutionService.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, ReferenceType refType)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.AggregateTypeResolutionService.GetType(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.AggregateTypeResolutionService.GetType(String name)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.DesignerSerializationManager.GetRuntimeType(String typeName)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.DesignerSerializationManager.GetType(String typeName)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.DesignerSerializationManager.System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.IDesignerSerializationManager.GetType(String typeName)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.GetType(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, String name, Dictionary`2 names)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.FillStatementTable(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, IDictionary table, Dictionary`2 names, CodeStatementCollection statements, String className)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.TypeCodeDomSerializer.Deserialize(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, CodeTypeDeclaration declaration)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager manager)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager serializationManager)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.DeferredLoadHandler.Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop.IVsTextBufferDataEvents.OnLoadCompleted(Int32 fReload)
```

Is there anything I'm missing?  What debug strategies can I use at this point?

This CPPProject project is required for my CSPROJECT.  If I remove the CPPProject, my application designs, but wont compile. I don't want to have to remove the reference every time I want to modify a form.

Comment: Have you tried to add the reference to the pre-compiled dll of your c++/CLI project? Also in order for this to work properly you need to have managed c++ method signatures to call from the C# code, otherwise you have to create a wrapper that does DLL import on your non-CLR c++ native code.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is the c++/cli and/or c# reference problem from the stack trace:

```
VSLangProj.Reference.get_Path()
```

Try removing any invalid references in your c++/cli and/or c# project. (Invalid references are marked with an exclamation point icon in project properties)